# how do I update a value in my table when I press a confirm button

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a code that brings data `idnumber` from a database and puts it into a select box.

If I select an `idnumber` from the select box and press a confirm button how can I write the code to update a column called "confirm" in the database from No to Yes?

The code below is the one for the select box

```
<select>
    <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","volunteer");
        /* check connection */

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
            $query = "SELECT * FROM registrations";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                echo "<option>" . $rows['idnumber'] . "</option>" ;
            }
    ?> 
</select>
<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="confirm-btn">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post the content of "confirm.php"

Comment: Where are you stuck? This is the type of thing you can see examples of in many many tutorials. Note though that no value for the select will be submitted to the server until you give it a name, and also the select needs to be within the form. Again, study HTML forms tutorials more closely, to learn the basics

Comment: The PHP manual has a section on [Dealing with Forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php). Give your `<select>` a `name` attribute so you can access it. And most of all, place it _inside_ your `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your select input under form tag
2. Give name to select box :
3. Click on confirm button.
4. Write code in : confirm.php

if (!empty($_POST['registrations'])) {

```
if (!empty($_POST['registrations'])) {
$sql = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME=".$_POST['registrations']."  where YOUR_CONDITION";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Form Input:**

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
<select name="idnumber">
    <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","volunteer");
        /* check connection */

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
            $query = "SELECT * FROM registrations";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
                echo "<option value=". $rows['idnumber'] .">" . $rows['idnumber'] . "</option>" ;
            }
    ?> 
</select>
    <button type="submit" name="confirm-btn">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

**Write code in : confirm.php**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","volunteer");
            /* check connection */

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }    

$sql = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME=".$_POST['idnumber']."  where YOUR_CONDITION";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
```